# Set pixel aspect ratio?

Tags: bugs, image-processing, image, display, rendering

**Bug partially fixed in 12.1** [CASE:4081592]

<sub>`ImageResolution` now works correctly for `Image`, but not for `Image3D`.</sub>

---

Does *Mathematica* have a feature to set the pixel aspect ratio of 2D images?

For example,

```
Image3DSlices[ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "CThead"}], 100, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can resize this to the correct aspect ratio, like so:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I do not want to modify the data. I just want to control how it is displayed.  With 3D images, we can use `BoxRatios`. What about 2D?

Comment: Something like `Graphics[Raster[ImageData[img, DataReversed -> True]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]`?

Comment: You can use `Show` with the `AspectRatio->1`, but the image quality is much lower. Or something like this: `ImageResize[yourimage, {#, #} &@Max@ImageDimensions[yourimage]]`. I work with images quite often but I don't know an option like `BoxRatios` that work with image objects.

Comment: From [Filling a rectangle with an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102811/35945): `VertexTextureCoordinates` looks like it could work. e.g. ``Graphics[{Texture[img], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, y}, {x, y}, {x, 0}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}]`` But it is quite verbose. I'm pretty sure there is an elegant way to convert an `Image` into a `Graphics` object.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Pre 11.0 or something `Rasterize` returned a `Graphics` object. You could see what format it used and try that. That could then of course take a direct `AspectRatio`, but I can’t try this right now.

Comment: @b3m2a1 `Head[Rasterize[img]]` returns `Image`, so it's no good.

Comment: @JungHwanMin you’ll need to supply a second argument. Look at the docs to figure out which one. Before version 11 the `Head` was `Graphics` and there will still be a way to get that behavior by the second argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alexey suggested that the following undocumented (but not going away) [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize) syntax could be used:

```
img = Image3DSlices[ExampleData[{"TestImage3D","CThead"}],100,3];
Show[img, ImageSize -> 1 -> {1,2}]
```

[image]

I think this does what you want?

Comment: Instead of `Show`, we could also use `Image`. One issue is that when resizing with the mouse, the aspect ratio jumps back to how it was. Where did Alexey show this syntax?

Comment: @Szabolcs In a comment to my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183265/45431) to a similar question, Alexey suggested that the same method might be useful for this question.

Answer (score 6):

### UPDATE

In version 12.1 they implemented correct handling of the `ImageResolution` option for `Image` (but for `Image3D` `ImageResolution` is still ignored).

---

### Original answer

<sub>*Note*: I've sent a suggestion for improvement to the tech support with a link to this post ([CASE:4081592]).</sub>

*Mathematica* already basically supports different resolutions in different directions for `Image` when importing and exporting (what is documented, for example, on the [Documentation page for `"JPEG"` format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JPEG.html#362709213)):

```
Options[img = Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", 
   ImageResolution -> {72, 144}], ImageResolution]

Options[Import@Export["coneflower_new.jpg", img], ImageResolution]
```

> ```
> {ImageResolution -> {72, 144}}
>
> {ImageResolution -> {72, 144}}
> ```

So [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) is [right](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175856/280): the developers just overlooked that this should also influence how the image is rendered by the FrontEnd. Other picture viewers respect this setting, for example here is how [Windows Photo Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Viewer) renders the image `"coneflower_new.jpg"`:

[image: screenshot]

As one can see from the screenshot, the image is scaled up two times in horizontal direction according to the specified `ImageResolution` which is two times smaller in horizontal direction (`72` dpi) than in vertical direction (`144` dpi), as expected.

But I think that it is incorrect to set `AspectRatio` of the whole image equal to pixel aspect ratio (as [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) [did](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175856/280)), because we should also take into account actual `ImageDimensions` when calculating the overall `AspectRatio`. So here is my fix for `Image` which makes it respecting the `ImageResolution` setting (I wrapped changed portions of the original code by `(* edit start *)` and `(* edit end *)` tags):

```
Unprotect[Image];
MakeBoxes[Image`ImageDump`img : Image[_, Image`ImageDump`type_, Image`ImageDump`info___], 
    Image`ImageDump`fmt_] /; Image`ValidImageQHold[Image`ImageDump`img] ^:= With[{
    Image`ImageDump`newarray = 
     Image`InternalImageData[Image`ImageDump`img, Interleaving -> True], 
    Image`ImageDump`tag = 
     BoxForm`ImageTag[Image`ImageDump`type, 
      Sequence @@ 
       FilterRules[FilterRules[{Image`ImageDump`info}, Except[Options["Graphics"]]], 
        Except[ImageMarkers]]], 
    Image`ImageDump`imgdata = 
     ImageData[Image`ImageDump`img, {"Width", "Height", "DataRange", "ColorFunction"}], 
    Image`ImageDump`imgsize = 
     Image`ImageDump`ruleValue[{Image`ImageDump`info}, ImageSize], 
    Image`ImageDump`mag = 
     Image`ImageDump`ruleValue[{Image`ImageDump`info}, Magnification],
    (* edit start *)
    Image`ImageDump`pixelAspectRatio = 
     With[{Image`ImageDump`res = 
        Image`ImageDump`ruleValue[{Image`ImageDump`info}, ImageResolution]},
      If[MatchQ[Image`ImageDump`res, {_?(# > 0 &), _?(# > 0 &)}],
       Divide @@ Image`ImageDump`res, 1, 1]
      ]
    (* edit end *)
    },
   With[{
     (* edit start *)
     Image`ImageDump`width = 
      Image`ImageDump`imgdata[[1]]/
       If[Image`ImageDump`pixelAspectRatio < 1, Image`ImageDump`pixelAspectRatio, 1, 1],
     Image`ImageDump`height = 
      Image`ImageDump`imgdata[[2]]*
       If[Image`ImageDump`pixelAspectRatio > 1, Image`ImageDump`pixelAspectRatio, 1, 1],
     (* edit end *)
     Image`ImageDump`range = Image`ImageDump`imgdata[[3]],
     Image`ImageDump`cfun = Image`ImageDump`imgdata[[4]]},
    With[{Image`ImageDump`options = Sequence @@ Join[{
          DefaultBaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics",
          ImageSizeRaw -> {Image`ImageDump`width, Image`ImageDump`height},
          PlotRange -> {{0, Image`ImageDump`width}, {0, Image`ImageDump`height}}
          }, 
         Image`ImageDump`ConvertImageSizeToFE[Image`ImageDump`imgsize, 
          Image`ImageDump`mag], 
         FilterRules[{Image`ImageDump`info}, Image`ImageDump`$typesetOptions]]}, 
     GraphicsBox[
      TagBox[RasterBox[
        Image`ImageDump`newarray, {{0, Image`ImageDump`height}, {Image`ImageDump`width, 
          0}}, Image`ImageDump`range, ColorFunction -> Image`ImageDump`cfun], 
       Image`ImageDump`tag, Selectable -> False], Image`ImageDump`options]]]];
Protect[Image];
```

Now

```
Import["coneflower_new.jpg"]
```

[image: screenshot]

```
Image[Image3DSlices[ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "CThead"}], 100, 3], 
 ImageResolution -> {72, 72/2}]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I was sloppy in my implementation. The displayed size of the image should take the resolution as an indicator of what aspect ratio one pixel has. I have described it correctly, but my implementation does not reflect this. When you get an answer from Wolfram, would you update Szabolcs question with the bug-head and tag it as bugs?

Comment: @halirutan Yes, I'll update the answer (and the question if relevant) with responce from the support when I receive it.

Comment: @halirutan I've received a responce: "I have passed along a report to our developers on this suggestion." If something more informative will come, I'll post an update.

Comment: @halirutan They fixed this bug for `Image` in version 12.1 (but not for `Image3D`).

Answer (score 4):

This might have been overlooked in the implementation of `Image`. When I see this right, then the correct way to handle this would be to respect the setting of `ImageResolution` and acknowledge that it can be different for different directions

[image]

and it is not unusual for medical devices like a CT to have a drastic difference in resolution for different directions. For a plain image, that doesn't know its resolution, the displayed size is always determined by assuming pixels are squares and using the `ImageDimension`-ratio as aspect-ratio.

However, I would have expected that something like this works

```
img = Image3DSlices[ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "CThead"}], 100, 3];
Image[img, ImageResolution -> {100, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately it doesn't, although the `GraphicsBox` would support it. But we could fix `MakeBoxes` for `Image` and we would get

[image]

Below are the changes I made as an image because it seems not easily possible to copy code from the `PrintDefinitions` view.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed surprisingly difficult. We have to set explicit `AspectRatio` and `ImageSize` (and optionally `Magnification`) after conversion into the corresponding `Graphics` object:

```
pixelAspectRatio = 2;
img = Image3DSlices[ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "CThead"}], 100, 3];

Show[img, 
 AspectRatio -> pixelAspectRatio*ImageAspectRatio[img], 
 ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]*{1, pixelAspectRatio}
 (*, BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 1*)]
```

Other options:

```
Show[img, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None,
  ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]*{1, pixelAspectRatio}
  (*, BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 1*)] /. 
 r_Raster :> Scale[r, {1, pixelAspectRatio}]

With[{is = ImageDimensions[img]*{1, pixelAspectRatio}}, 
 Show[img, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> is
   (*, BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 1*)] /. 
  Raster[array_, _, opts___] :> Raster[array, {{0, 0}, is}, opts]]
```

---

We can avoid conversion into a `Graphics` object by using `Style` for changing the default options of `GraphicsBox` locally. Unfortunately via `GraphicsBoxOptions` we can't  change `ImageSize` stored in the `Image` object itself, hence we should change it directly via `Image`:

```
Style[Image[img, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]*{1, pixelAspectRatio}],
 GraphicsBoxOptions ->
  {AspectRatio -> pixelAspectRatio*ImageAspectRatio[img] 
   (*, BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 1*)}]
```

`ImageSize -> All` also works:

```
Style[Image[img, ImageSize -> All], GraphicsBoxOptions ->
  {AspectRatio -> pixelAspectRatio*ImageAspectRatio[img]
   (*, BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 1*)}]
```

We can prove that the displayed size is indeed correct by rasterizing the output and taking its `"RasterSize"`:

```
ImageDimensions[img]
Rasterize[PreviousCell[], "RasterSize"]
```

> ```
> {256, 99}
>
> {256, 198}
> ```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +1 for the info that `Style` can be used. I looked through the complete `MakeBoxes` of `Image` to see if I can somehow inject this option so that you don't have either fix the code or use a wrapper like `Style`. Seems not possible with `Image` alone.